# Redux action fires twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

**I have this redux todo app that updates the state of the remaining tasks based on the number of incomplete tasks.**

**The app is working without any errors or problems but when I add a task, toggle completion, and remove a task, the action type of `remainingTasks/updateRemainingTasks` fires twice:**

[image]

[image]

**Interestingly, that action only fires once when removing a task that has been completed:**

[image]

**These are the code for that slice and its corresponding component:**

**SLICE**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const remainingTasksSlice = createSlice({
  name: "remainingTasks",
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    updateRemainingTasks: (state, action) => {
      return action.payload;
    },
  },
});

// Selectors
export const selectRemainingTasksSlice = (state) => state.remainingTasksReducer;

// Actions
export const { updateRemainingTasks } = remainingTasksSlice.actions;

// Reducers
export default remainingTasksSlice.reducer;
```

**COMPONENT**

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  selectRemainingTasksSlice,
  updateRemainingTasks,
} from "./remainingTasksSlice";
import { selectTaskSlice } from "../task/taskSlice";

const RemainingTasks = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const remainingTasksSlice = useSelector(selectRemainingTasksSlice);
  const taskSlice = useSelector(selectTaskSlice);

  // Number of Incomplete Tasks
  const incompleteTasks = taskSlice.filter((task) => !task.completed).length;

  // Update the State of the Remaining Tasks
  dispatch(updateRemainingTasks(incompleteTasks));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="header">
        {remainingTasksSlice > 1
          ? `${remainingTasksSlice} Tasks Left`
          : `${remainingTasksSlice} Task Left`}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RemainingTasks;
```

**I was wondering if this is a normal thing or my code isn't well optimized.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to call dispatch into a useEffect hook:

```
....
useEffect(()=>{
    // Number of Incomplete Tasks
    const incompleteTasks = taskSlice.filter((task) => !task.completed).length;
    // Update the State of the Remaining Tasks
    dispatch(updateRemainingTasks(incompleteTasks));
}, [taskSlice]);
....
```

otherwise you call dispatch every time you render the Component.

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem. But now I'm getting this warning:
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: Adding 'dispatch' to the dependency array fixed the warning.